# Adding two addreses

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, ida

I have executable which I'm investigating for educational purposes. I'm using IDA pro to understand the purpose of executable but have few questions. Here is my code:

```
1.text:00401525                 call    ebp ; MapViewOfFile
2.text:00401527                 mov     ebp, eax
3.text:00401529                 test    ebp, ebp
4.text:0040152B                 mov     [esp+54h+argv], ebp ; argv-shi ari chemi dll gadmotanili
5.text:0040152F                 jnz     short loc_401538
6.text:00401531                 push    eax             ; Code
7.text:00401532                 call    ds:exit
8.text:00401538 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
9.text:00401538
10.text:00401538 loc_401538:                             ; CODE XREF: _main+EFj
11.text:0040154C                 mov     esi, [ebp+3Ch]
12.text:0040154F                 push    ebp
13.text:00401550                 add     esi, ebp
14.text:00401552                 mov     ebx, eax
15.text:00401554                 push    esi
16.text:00401555                 mov     [esp+68h+var_30], ebx
17.text:00401559                 mov     ecx, [esi+78h]
18.text:0040155C                 push    ecx
19.text:0040155D                 call    sub_401040
```

I did the enumeration just to simplify my question. 
As you can see on line 1 `MapViewofFile` function is called, the address returned is stored in `ebp` and then in `argv` (just to be clear `kernel32.dll` was the file being mapped).

After that on line 11 (As I understand) some functions pointer was moved in `esi`. `3ch` in decimal is `60` and each function is 4 byte, I listed all the functions exported from `kernel32.dll` and found that 15th function is `AddSecureMemoryCacheCallback`. Then `ebp` is pushed on the stack and on line 13 I got totally confused. As I understand it would add the pointer of `kernel32.dll`s beginning to the pointer which points to `AddSecureMemoryCacheCallback` which is nonsense, but I could not think of anything that it could do, what is the purpose of this? Sorry if my question sounds silly, I'm new with assembly and I could not paste the whole code because it's too big. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you're looking at the export list. If `kernel32.dll` was mapped from the beginning, then `ebp` is pointing at its MZ header. Offset 60 in there is `e_lfanew` which is the offset to the PE header.

Comment: thank you so much :) As I said I'm new with assembly and didn't know what too look at, but its still unclear to me what `add edi, esi` does. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function calls [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **Return value**
>   If the function succeeds, the return value is the starting address of the mapped view.
>   If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

This is optimized code, so `ebp` is used as a general purpose register, not as a base pointer.

```
1   call    ebp ; MapViewOfFile
2   mov     ebp, eax            //EBP = start address of mapped view.
3   test    ebp, ebp            //Success or failure?
4   mov     [esp+54h+argv], ebp //save mapped address in a variable
5   jnz     short loc_401538    //Success -> jump to loc_401538
6   push    eax                 //failure -> clean up and exit.  
7   call    ds:exit
8 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
9
10 loc_401538:                             ; CODE XREF: _main+EFj
11  mov     esi, [ebp+3Ch]       //esi = MappedFile.SomeOffset at addr 60 in the mapped file
12  push    ebp                  //Param3 =  Addr(MappedFile)               
13  add     esi, ebp             //esi = pointer(MappedFile.SomeOffset)
14  mov     ebx, eax             //ebx = start of mapped file
15  push    esi                  //Param2 = pointer(MappedFile.SomeOffset)
16  mov     [esp+68h+var_30], ebx //store start of mapped file in some var
17  mov     ecx, [esi+78h]       //ecx = MappedFile.SomeOffset-> = 120 
18  push    ecx                  //Param1 = MappedFile.SomeOffset[120]
19  call    sub_401040           //call subroutine(Param1, Param2, Param3)
```

The subroutine is a function with 3 parameters using the [`cdecl` calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). Param2 and Param3 are pointers into the mapped file and param1 is some unknown data.
If you know the filename of the file being mapped, then you can use a hexeditor, to look at the data and (possibly) see which offset is stored at Offset 60 and then calculate what data is stored at offset: `[0+offset[60]][120]`.

Note that most likely the subroutine called returns a value, because `eax` is made available.

**About your comments**
Your assumption that this snippet calls functions in `Kernel32.dll` is incorrect. All pointers point into the buffer returned by `MapViewOfFile` and you'll have to study the contents of that particular file to understand what the code is doing.

The pushing of registers is simply the `cdecl` calling convention at work. Because this is `c` code it uses the `cdecl` calling convention internally which requires all parameters to be transferred using the stack.
Externally it uses [`stdcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) which transfers the first 3 params in registers.

Both `stdcall` and `cdecl` return their result in `EAX`.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer :) but on line 13, `add esi, ebp` shoould not it be `lea esi, ebp` to move the pointer of  `MappedFile.SomeOffset` in to esi?

Comment: I'm sure you meant `lea esi,[ebp+esi]`. Yes that would work, but  `add reg,reg` is 2 bytes and a `lea reg,[reg+reg]` is 3 bytes, so the add is more efficient. The last offset @120, is dereferenced using a pointer to a pointer. So you need 2 steps to get there, hence the add.

Comment: sorry I'm little confused, Should not `add` instruction sum the values stored in registers? Why does it store pointer of one register into another?

Comment: @Rasty pointer is a value too, you can add two pointers if you want. Usually it will have no meaning, but pointer plus offset/index is often used, in this case it looks like `esi` contains some kind of offset/index, while `ebp` is some starting address, so together they form address of some particular interesting value. Either way, in 32b protected x86 mode the pointer is just 32 bit value, just like any other 32b value (including "int" numbers) and you can apply on it all the arithmetic you wish. Whether it makes sense and result is usable pointer, that's up to programmer/code.